# django increase inactivity timeout

Tags: django

If I am logged into my Django site but am inactive for a while it automatically logs me out.  Is there a way to stop this all together or at least increase the timeout to say an hour or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing session cookies age. There is a setting: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-cookie-age